# Tableau multiple Dimension

Tags: tableau-api

I have below raw data table

**Table Name: RawData**
`Mode   Country      Month    Visitor
Air     Switzerland  Sep-16   Rob
Air     Switzerland  Oct-16   Bob
Air     Switzerland  Nov-16   Ben
Air     Rome         Sep-16   Zen
Air     Rome         Sep-16   Jen
Air     Rome         Oct-16   Todd
Air     Rome         Nov-16   Ron
Air     Italy        Sep-16   John
Air     Italy        Sep-16   Scott
Air     Italy        Sep-16   Jeff
Air     Italy        Oct-16   Audrey
Air     Italy        Nov-16   Steve
Ground  Switzerland  Sep-16   Rob
Ground  Switzerland  Oct-16   Russel
Ground  Switzerland  Oct-16   Zen
Ground  Rome         Nov-16   Ron
Ground  Italy        Sep-16   Dan
Ground  Italy        Oct-16   Timmy
Ground  Italy        Oct-16   Auidrey
Water   Switzerland  Sep-16   Peter
Water   Switzerland  Sep-16   Josh
Water   Switzerland  Nov-16   Rob
Water   Rome         Oct-16   Ben
Water   Rome         Nov-16   Stuart
Water   Rome         Nov-16   Jen
Water   Rome         Nov-16   Todd
Water   Italy        Sep-16   Scott
Water   Italy        Sep-16   Jeff
Water   Italy        Sep-16   LOLO
Water   Italy        Sep-16   Dabbu
Water   Italy        Nov-16   Danu
Water   Italy        Oct-16   Randy
Water   Italy        Oct-16   Demi`

Based on above raw data, I want to create below count table and plot it:

**Table Name: DesiredData**
`Count of Visitors in all Sep, Oct, Nov

            Switzerland   Rome    Italy
Air           3            4         5
Ground        3            2         3
Water         3            4         7
Grandtotal    9           10        15`

So basically, I am trying to plot above "DesiredData" table in from above "RawData" table.

Once I have this "DesiredData" table, **I want to use Grandtotal as shown in that table to create a chart that has X-Axis as Mode and Y-Axis as Country**

Not sure, how to create multiple charts from the above raw data.

[Sample chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InjmT.png)

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place **Mode** dimension into Rows, **Country** into Columns, and then drag **Visitor** to the "Text" tab under the "Marks" shelf. Then, Right-click on the "Visitor" pill and then click on "Measure" and select "Count" or "Count (Distinct)"

Is the result what you are looking for?

The above process is for Tableau Desktop. I haven't worked on Tableau-server before, but I assume the process is the same.

**Summary Update**-
Place only "Country" on the Columns, place only CNT(Visitor) in Rows and drag "Mode" on the Color tab under Marks shelf

Comment: Thank you Vamsi. I could get those numbers.Once I have above numbers in place, I want to use those total numbers to create a chart  with X-axis as Mode and Y-Axis as Country. (I forgot mentioning that in the post earlier..Sorry about that)

Comment: Can you tell me what kind of chart you are looking for? Is it a heat map?

Comment: if you don't think you can explain it, showing it with an image link after googling also works..

Comment: Its a bar chart. I have a sample image but not sure, how to post an image here

Comment: From what I understand, place 'Mode' into Columns and 'Country' into Rows  and finally drag the CNT(Visitor) from Marks into the Rows shelf beside the 'Mode' pill.

Comment: Doing above, does not let me make it Dual Axis. So, without Dual Axis it shows three small graphs instead of one.

Comment: Not sure why you would have Dual axis. You should only see one green pill among both rows and columns shelf. Hence there won't be a case for Dual axis.
It is best if you can google some bar chart images and share the relevant image link in your question or (last resort) upload a picture after hand-drawing it on a piece of paper

Comment: I added sample chart to the question. Thank you so much for guiding me on this.

Comment: ok. that makes things a lot clear! 
Place only "Country" on the Columns, place only CNT(Visitor) in Rows and drag "Mode" on the Color tab under Marks shelf.

Comment: @Tableau Beginner Welcome to Stack Overflow and Tableau. Be sure to accept the answer so Vamsi gets some reputation on SO for the time he spent helping you

Comment: Hi Alex, How do I do that. I tried checking the previous answer, but the later part of the answer @Vamsi provided was what I was looking for. Thanks for guiding!